# Error connecting to smtp server

Tags: nodes, emails

I have a Drupal 7.30 installation that I'm trying to develop on webenabled ( I also had it on network solutions shared hosting), and every time I attempt to send an email, I get the error unable to connect to the smtp server, and unable to send email, contact the system admin if this persists.
I have read numerous articles and check the drupal forum, but I have had no luck. None of the solutins work for me. I'm wondering if it is the configuration on the shared hosting. That is why I left network solutions. They culd not help, and were rather rude about my attempts.
Thank you ahead of time for anyone that can provide an answer.
SimmonsOne (Drupal username)

Comment: Drupal should be able to send emails out of the box.  First check if you have any mail modules installed ie.. https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp since this can hijack the normal mail system.  If you are using a fresh installation, it is most likely going to be server related.  Your host should be able to help you through it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a mail system installed on your server, Drupal will use it to send mail.

Things to check:

1. Can you send mail using a CLI mail program (e.g. "mail")?
2. Can PHP send [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)? (Create a small PHP program outside of Drupal that uses this PHP-function to send mail.)

Usually, this is not a Drupal problem.  If you're able to send mail *outside* of Drupal, then Drupal will also send mail without any special configuration on your part.

Most shared hosting plans I've used (never used *Network Solutions*) is set up to send mail by default.

Also read this about [debugging](http://www.webomelette.com/drupal-modules-debug-emails) email problems.